# How to make work apache commons and gwt via Maven?

Tags: gwt, maven

I use GWT and a lot of classes from apache commons in a project. After changing ant to maven the conflicts with apache commons and gwt-dev appeared. Without gwt-dev lib dependency (but with manual set to classpath in order to use GWT Dev Mode) the following errors appear:

> [ERROR] /project/branches/maven/server/project-server/target/generated-sources/gwt/com/project/client/Service_TypeSerializer.java:[20,3] cannot find symbol
>
> [ERROR] symbol  : class GwtScriptOnly
>
> [ERROR] location: class com.project.client.Service_TypeSerializer

There are no /gwt/com/project/client folders in /project/branches/maven/server/project-server/target/generated-sources/.

With gwt-dev dependencies project doesn't build at all.

Are there any solution on how to resolve apache commons and gwt conflicts?

Comment: What errors do you get when `gwt-dev` is used ?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov  Failed to execute goal com.ning.maven.plugins:maven-duplicate-finder-plugin:1.0.3:check (default) on project project: Found duplicate classes/resources -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.ning.maven.plugins:maven-duplicate-finder-plugin:1.0.3:check (default) on project project: Found duplicate classes/resources
and build failed.

Comment: Ok, so it's about duplicated classes. Execute `mvn dependency:tree` and post output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [*known issue*](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4484), but actually I believe you should put your client and server code in separate Maven modules.
It's cleaner: separation of concerns, also separates client dependencies from server dependencies –which would fix your issue–, and doesn't unnecessarily package your client classes into the `WEB-INF/classes`.

Have a look at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes for one way to do it (see also the [announcement](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/announcing-gwt-maven-archetypes-project) which has a bit of background).